# Question regarding the sail attached to a boat.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, energy-conservation

I came across a physics numerical in which the boat is travelling 45 degrees south-east. The direction of wind is towards north and the force that it exerts is constant force of 100 N on the sail.
The issue I am having is that the initial Kinetic energy is much less than energy lost(force of wind * cos (45) * distance traveled)  because of the force of wind.
Is it possible that the ship will cover the distance stated in numerical?

Comment: Relevant: http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/~jw/sailing.html

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. "The distance stated" - what distance is this? Are you asking in general about the physics of sailing, or a particular (partially stated) problem? What is the "initial kinetic energy" you speak of - the wind, or the boat? This could be a very interesting question but it needs some work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make some general comments, expecting that they will lead for further clarification of the question.

First - when a boat sails into the wind (as the one in this question does), it is important to realize that (all these are idealized statements... real sailing is a lot more complicated):

a) the force of the wind is approximately normal to the sail
b) the sail is approximately bisecting the angle between the wind and the boat
c) the wind does not *stop*, but *bends* around the sail
d) there is a lateral force from the keel - which prevents the boat from drifting sideways; only the forward component of the wind moves the boat.

So with the boat at 45° to the wind, and the sail at 22.5° to the boat, the force pushing the boat forward is

$$F = 100 \cdot \sin(22.5°) = 38 N$$

[image]

(I drew the boat as though the wind is coming from the top of the page, as that is how I have done it for years. You would have to call that "South" for your situation. I just can't bring myself to draw the other way up. It doesn't change the concept. Sorry?)

Now drag of a boat is approximately quadratic with velocity - so there is a "sufficiently low" velocity where the drag is less than this 38 N, and the boat arrives (eventually) at its destination.

I realize this may be an oversimplification - so I invite you to ask questions to further clarify this.